# Android Video listing from remote server?

Tags: android, android-listview

I use my application to upload the video in server and it was stored in appropriate folder in server, i need to show the list of video from remote server folder and allow the user to streaming the video.Is there any sample is there?

Answer (score 0):

I feel you can have a script running on server which tells you about which directory has what videos, and returns their URLs too.

Later, you can access those URLs to play the videos

Answer (score 0):

You can use commons-net-2.2-bin library to create a FTP connection to your server and make a query of listing *.* files from the folder.